# Most suitable phrase that has equivalent meaning with " Terms that make the warranty invalid "

Tags: phrases, expressions, titles

I am preparing a document for our company's new product (industrial machinery). In the documentation there must be a special part which should list some terms and conditions that make our warranty invalid.

For example, there is a 5 year warranty for the product. However, when the user does not obey some special rules (not using the machine properly, changing parts without our knowledge, not operating within maximum documented capability limits, etc.), the warranty ends immediately (not in 5 years).

- **What is possibly the most suitable phrase to name that part of the document?**

Comment: I would just call them warranty conditions

Comment: @minty Alternatively 'exclusion conditions' or 'invalidation conditions'

Answer (score 0):

'NOTICE' can be used over here as it giving out a notification or a warning